# Passing list to pool.map() function in Python returns each character for each item in the list

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, pool

This Python 2.7 script running on Windows is not outputting as I would expect it to.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def function1():
    function1List = ["11" ,'22' , '33']
    return function1List

def function2(passedList):
    for item in passedList:
        print item

list = function1()
#print list    used to verify list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ThreadPool()
    pool.map(function2, list)
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
```

What I expect

```
11
22
33
44
```

What I am actually getting

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is passing one item of each list to `function2`.

And then, inside `function2`, you're iterating over that item, getting each character of the string.

It's exactly the same as if you'd written this:

```
values = ["11" ,'22' , '33']
for value in values:
    for item in value:
        print item
```

---

So, how do you fix it? Well, it depends what you want.

If you want each task to get a single list item, as it currently does, you just need to change `function2` to expect that:

```
def function2(item):
    print item
```

If you want each task to get a list, you have to change the thing you call `map` on into a list of lists. I'm not sure what lists you want, but you could pass four single-element lists:

```
values = [[value] for value in values]
```

… or one four-element list:

```
values = [values]
```

… or two two-element interleaved lists:

```
values = [values[::2], values[1::2]]
```

… or anything else you want.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Function2 actually needs to accept each item of the list and run each item through another loop. That is why I put the loop in function2 to test this. Function1 creates a list through webcrawling. Function2 loops through each item of that list and does stuff to it. The code above is me trying to use multiprocessing on function2

Comment: @olaHalo That will work, but it’s not doing you much good. You only have a single task that way, so why even use a pool in the first place?

Comment: I finally wrapped my head around it. Pool.map(method, argument) is already looping for me. So what I was doing with function2 was looping it again which was causing it to break down each character. You clearly explained it but it did not click until now.

Comment: @olaHalo Exactly. This is one of those things that's obvious once it clicks, but a huge pain to work through until it does; everyone goes through that…